# How to rename a group of files by moving a pattern within the file names

Tags: sed, rename, file-rename

For the files

```
test_001.log
test_002.log
```

I would like to rename them to

```
001_test.log
002_test.log
```

I think it should be something like

```
for f in *.log; do mv "$f" "`echo $f | sed s/test_\(.*\)\.log/\1_test.log/`"; done
```

but I get the error

```
mv: `test_001.log' and `test_001.log' are the same file
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working snippet:

```
for f in *.log; do mv $f `echo $f | sed 's/test_\(.*\)\.log/\1_test.log/'`; done;
```

I think you missed to quote `'s/test_\(.*\)\.log/\1_test.log/'` and that might not returning what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with just shell parameter expansion and without external tools:

```
$ for f in *.log; do fnew=${f#test_}; echo mv "$f" "${fnew%.log}"_test.log; done
mv test_001.log 001_test.log
mv test_002.log 002_test.log
```

Remove the `echo` to actually execute these commands.

Notice that the unquoted `$f` in your command might make it break for filenames with spaces or shell meta characters because of word splitting and path expansion.